# I don't receive any logs from azure container instance whereas logs are in the container tab

Tags: azure-container-instances

I've launched my instance with the right --log-analytics-workspace and --log-analytics-workspace-key.
I can see ContainerEvent_CL logs.
but I can see no ContainerInstanceLog_CL logs.

I'm using gcr.io/distroless/cc-debian10:nonroot as image
and logging with rust tracing library at info level.
I can see logs in the container logs tab.
Container is running properly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The logs finally came in, 12h or so later.